# Why is it showing me column1, column2 instead of the names of the columns?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, analytics, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

I am working on the power bi project and i can't figure out how to see the names of the columns ..
I have loaded data in csv format so please elaborate how can i fix this?[image]

I am expecting to see the names of the columns instead of column1, column2.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Transform Data and see if the first row of your CSV has column headers.  If so tell Power Query to use the first row as headers.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/table-promote-demote-headers